# Continuous loop to refresh formulas

Tags: vba, function, excel, loops

I have a worksheet that is using =Files as a named range (so I can see files in a folder. I then have a MOVE button that can move files from one folder to another.
When I click the command button I have told it perform the move and

```
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
```

Which works fantastic.
The only thing is that only updates my list of files when I click the move button

Is there anyway to have this function be working at all times?
Without clicking a button.....
So as long as the file is open it is always performing that refresh.

Ideally I would be able to tell it to do it every X seconds....but that is not necessary.

Comment: if you leave code running endlessly in an open workbook you will be *severely* hampered in working with Excel throughout your day. You could however, create a `vbscript` to open the workbook in a separate Excel instance and run the code, then close the workbook. And then use the Task Scheduler to schedule the vbscript to run every X seconds throughout the day.

Comment: The situation would be that the file is on a computer that does nothing but run that excel file all day. Absolutely nothing else.  Because i need the excel file open all day.Would it be ok then?

Comment: You can use `Application.OnTime()` to update on a periodic basis.

Comment: You don't have to turn calculation off and back on again to make Excel calculate, you can just use `Application.Calculate`.

Comment: see my answer based on your last comment CORNAKI.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Application on time sounds great....but where do i paste that....on my 'thisworkbook' page? And in between what? a function sub?     I do not want to be putting this in button code, because i want it to run always.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you are **only** using this workbook on a machine doing **nothing** else, you can place your code in the `workbook_open` event of your workbook (ThisWorkbook module in the VBE) and surround it with a `Do Loop` like below.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Do

    'code to move files

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:05:00"))  'waits 5 minutes       

Loop Until Time() >= TimeValue("17:00:00") '5pm military time

ThisWorkbook.Close True 'closes workbook after loop is over

End Sub
```

This code will execute **as soon as you open your workbook** and essentially continue until a defined time period in the day, then close the workbook, pausing the loop every x minutes (set by Application.Wait).

### Alternate Approach

Alternatively, as Tim Williams suggested, you can use a loop with the `Application.OnTime` command like this

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim t as Date
t = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") 'just give a 5 seconds to start loop

Do 

  Application.OnTime t, "mySub" 'where mySub is your sub name

  t = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00") 'sets t to 5 minutes from now

Loop Until t > = TimeValue("17:00:00")

ThisWorkbook.Close True

End Sub
```